# SQL create rows with dates at the end of quarter from rows with two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, recursive-query

I have at table, where i need to create a new table based on two dates in the first table. The first table looks like below with the date format YYYY-MM-DD:

```
Start date | End date   | Data
2015-09-01 | 2016-07-15 | 500
2016-05-01 | 2017-01-01 | 600
```

What I need the table to do is take all the end of quarter dates there might be in between the two dates in each row, and create new rows with the data like this:

```
Date       | Data
2015-09-30 | 500
2015-12-31 | 500
2016-03-31 | 500
2016-06-30 | 500
2016-06-30 | 600
2016-09-30 | 600
2016-12-31 | 600
```

There are more rows than the two above. Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks :-)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your question would be much clearer if you used YYYY-MM-DD as the date format.

Comment: Create a table somehow (lots of different ways) that have all the end-of-quarter dates in it (one column, many rows).  Join that table to your table `on quarters.date >= startdate and quarters.date <= enddate`.  Inner join if you only want actual data, otherwise full join and use `isnull(data, 0)` in your select statement to show 0 data (or you can leave it null or do whatever you want with nulls).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a recursive query. The logic is to iterate over the end of quarters until the date range is exhausted:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        id,
        dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, start_date) + 1, -1) start_date,
        end_date,
        data
    from mytable
    union all
    select
        id,
        dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, dateadd(month, 4, start_date)), -1),
        end_date,
        data
    from cte
    where start_date < dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, end_date), -1)
)
select cast(start_date as date) start_date, data from cte order by id, start_date
```

I added an  `id` column to uniquely identify each record in the starting table. This is not strictly needed for the query, but it allows to properly order the records in the resultset.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75e88430218665fd0b041090e1bf42c6)**

Sample data:

```
id | start_date | end_date   | data
-: | :--------- | :--------- | ---:
 1 | 2015-09-01 | 2016-07-15 |  500
 2 | 2016-05-01 | 2017-01-01 |  600
```

Query results:

```
start_date | data
:--------- | ---:
2015-09-30 |  500
2015-12-31 |  500
2016-03-31 |  500
2016-06-30 |  500
2016-06-30 |  600
2016-09-30 |  600
2016-12-31 |  600
```